# Does the inheritance of opencv functions make my program better?

Tags: c++, opencv, refactoring

I have a program that uses opencv functions such as `calibratecamera`. Now I am working on the final version of my code, and I was wondering if instead of calling opencv's functions I inherit them in my classes would make my program 'better' ?

Comment: What does 'better' even mean? In what units is 'better' measured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is a library with well defined API. If you have an existing application that uses functions bundled within this library and you don't have a valid reason for adding an additional functionality to them, there is no advantage that you could gain by wrapping them.

If you want to change the interface because you think it will make your code cleaner, I would worry about the maintenance in case the API will change in the future.

While changing the ***design*** of your applications, your ***decisions should be based on specific reasons***. *"I want to make my program better"* is too abstract one.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, your question is very "general" and somehow confused. However, there is a general answer to the question "is it better to inherit?". Of course, being a general answer, it is oversimplified and might not apply to your case.

Item 58 in "C++ Coding Standards" (Sutter, Alexandrescu), is titled

> Prefer composition to inheritance

You can find similar advice in several other books too.

The reason they give for making their case is:

> Avoid inheritance taxes: Inheritance is the second-tightest coupling relationship in 
>   C++, second only to friendship. Tight coupling is undesirable and should be 
>   avoided where possible. Therefore, prefer composition to inheritance unless you 
>   know that the latter truly benefits your design.

So, the general advise is to **try and avoid inheritance** as much as possible, and always being conservative on using it, **unless you have a very strong case for it**. For instance, you have a case for the use of public inheritance if you are modelling the so called **"is-a" relationship**. On the other hand, you have a case for using nonpublic inheritance if you are in one of the following situations:

- If you need to override a virtual function
- If you need access to a protected member

or in other less frequent cases.

Whatever your final choice is, be sure to only inherit from classes that have been designed in order to be base classes. For instance, be sure that the base class destructor is virtual. As the cited book poses it:

> Using a standalone class as a base is a  serious design error and
>   should be avoided. To add behavior, prefer to add  nonmem-ber
>   functions instead of member functions (see Item 44). To add state,
>   prefer  composition instead of inheritance (see Item 34). Avoid
>   inheriting from concrete base  classes

Comment: The problem is that although OP wrote *"I inherit them in my classes"*, he was most likely not truly referring to inheritance, especially while giving `calibratecamera` as an example.

Comment: what do you think he was referring to?

Comment: I believe that the true question here was whether it makes a sense (yields any advantage) to provide a custom interface for a OpenCV's functions (i.e. instead of `cv::calibratecamera` taking 8 parameters he would create something like `myClass::calibratecamera` taking 4 parameters)...